# C++ Block Scope and Local Scope

Tags: c++

Going through some parts in this tutorial here: https://www.learncpp.com/, are there any major differences between 'Block Scope' and 'Local Scope'? Or are they just synonyms?

From what I understand:

Block Scope - Scope starts from the opening curly brace `{`, ends at the closing curly brace `}`.

Local Scope - Scope starts from the initialization of function parameters, ends at the functions closing curly brace `}`.

Comment: To my understanding, they are much the same, seeing how the function body can be interpreted as 'block' as well. As long as you understand that all variables declared in hierarchically higher blocks are valid in lower blocks as well, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

People say that variable is in block scope, when they want to emphasize that it's really an object that does not exist outside the block in which they are declared and might reuse the name for something else, like counter in for-loop. However, based on definition they are synonyms. In unit testing I usually enclose separate test inputs in different block scopes, so I don't have to deal with name collisions.

Comment: Be careful with terminology here: a "temporary object" is created on the fly in an expression (typically by calling a function that returns an object) and lives only until the end of the **expression** it's created in. In `std::cout << f() << '\n';`, where `f()` returns, say, an `int`, the function call creates a temporary object that goes away at the `;`.

Comment: sure, edited to clarify.